# Algorithm to find a set of words in a large list of words

Tags: algorithm, search, groovy, time-complexity, text-search

I'm looking for the fastest algorithm that can find a set of words matching another set of words in a list of 9 million records.

Problem: I have a list with almost 100,000 sets of words and I need to search for a match of each of the word set in another list of 9 million sets of words.

My current solution goes like this, I read all the records (from a text file) and keep in memory (in form of an array, let's call it 'search list'). While building this array, I sort the set of words alphabetically and once all the word sets are added, I sort the whole list. I do the same with the other big list, let's call that 'data list'.

Now I iterate over each of elements in my search list and try to find a match. Once a match is found I remember the position at which it matched and the next search I do from the same position. This saves me from iterating the whole data list again and again for each element in the search list.

I assumed it to be super fast but unfortunately, it's not. It almost takes 15 to 20 mins to complete full iteration of the search list. This is not acceptable.

Here is a snippet of my code

```
 int lastPointer = 0
 for(int i=0; i<search list.size(); i++){       
    def this_matched_out = []
    inmem_json_arr[i][0]
    for(int j=lastPointer; j<data list.size(); j++){
        if(data list[j].containsAll(search list[i])){
            this_matched_out.add(data list[j])
            lastPointer = j
        }
    }
    if(this_matched_out.size()>0) - println "found a match for search "+list[i]
    else println "No match found for "+list[i] 
}
```

Can anybody suggest me a better algorithm or am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to store the search terms in a map/associative array and then look up each word in the long list? You woldn't have to sort the long list. (I'm also not sure why you have to sort the lists when you insert items. Isn't it enough to sort each array once after reading?)

Comment: This feels like something that makes more sense to insert into a database and write a very simple join query.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use a hash table.  A lookup takes O(1) time no matter how big your set of words is.